# Why isn't my text bouncing left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jb9mt/196/)** works but when I place it into my `index.html` it won't work. I think it's the `<span>` tags. Is there a different tag I can use?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0,
        $chars  = $(".arthed").children();
    
    setInterval(function () {
        $chars.eq(counter).effect( "bounce", {times:1}, 500 );
        counter++;
        if (counter >= $chars.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 250);
});
```

```css
.arthed {
    font-family: montserrat;
}
.ui-effects-wrapper {
    display : inline-block;
    font-family: montserrat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="arthed"><span>s</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span> <span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span></div>
```

Comment: The example you've given works just fine - so there's not much we can do to help you. Did you forget to load jQuery in your `index.html`?

Comment: How do you go about that? This is my first time using jquery.

Comment: You also need jQuery UI. Just include the two `<script>` tags I've updated your code sample to use. Ideally, they go in your `<head>` section. I'd also recommend reading up on the [**basics of jQuery**](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Answer (score 0):

It should be some issue related to fonts and text rendering (even also). Your snippet bounces left to right and after changing font to `sans`, at least on my device, stops horizontal bounces.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0,
    $chars = $(".arthed").children();
  setInterval(function() {
    $chars.eq(counter).effect("bounce", {
      times: 1
    }, 500);
    counter++;
    if (counter >= $chars.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }
  }, 250);
});
```

```css
.arthed {
  font-family: sans;
}

.ui-effects-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="arthed">
  <span>s</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>m</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>t</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>x</span>
  <span>t</span>
</div>
```

So, maybe the only way to prevent it from bouncing left and right could be saving the width of the span before animation and fix the width. This snippet is dirty working example. Using `position: absolute`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 0,
    $chars = $(".arthed").children();
  $chars.each((i,el) => {el.style.left=el.offsetLeft+"px"});
  $chars.each((i,el) => {el.style.position="absolute"})
  setInterval(function() {
    $chars.eq(counter).effect("bounce", {
      times: 1
    }, 500);
    counter++;
    if (counter >= $chars.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }
  }, 250);
});
```

```css
.arthed {
  font-family: montserrat;
  position: absolute;
}

.ui-effects-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: montserrat;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="arthed">
<span>s</span><span>o</span><span>m</span><span>e</span>
<span>t</span><span>e</span><span>x</span><span>t</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to bounce left to right, I'm just having troubles getting it to work in my index.html. The jsfiddle works for me though

Comment: @johnstont05 I have no idea about that, [bounce effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/) only vertical. Maybe you need to move to [shake effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/shake-effect/)